# Как сгенерировать случайное число с 6 знаками после запятой?(JavaScript)

Tags: генерация-случайных-данных

Как сгенерировать случайное число с 6 знаками после запятой, например 0.582943 и можно ли задать ему интервал, между числами у которых тоже 6 знаков после запятой, например от 0.200000 до 1 или наподобии?

Comment: какой ЯП нужен?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не корректно составлен (нету ЯП), но предположу ответ на 2х популярных ЯП - `C#` и `Python`.

Python для вашего примера

```
round(random.uniform(0.2, 1),6)
```

То есть:

```
round(random.uniform(%Начальное значение%, %Конечное значение%),%Число знаков после запятой%)
```

C# для вашего примера:

```
Convert.ToDouble(x.Next(20000,100000)/100000.0)
```

То есть:

```
Convert.ToDouble(x.Next(%Начальное значение% * %10^число знаков после запятой%,%конечное значение% * %10^число знаков после запятой%)/%10^число знаков после запятой%.0)
```

Comment: А язык то оказался `JavaScript`, судя по ответу самого автора вопроса ))

Comment: Вот примерно поэтому я считаю, что не надо писать ответы на плохо оформленные вопросы

Comment: @andreymal, иногда (редко, но бывает) плохо оформленный вопрос случайно содержит глубокую задачу. В этих случаях можно? :)

Answer (score 1):

`randomInRange` выдаёт случайное целое число в диапазоне `[a, b)`:

```
const randomInRange = (a, b) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a)) + a;
```

Использовать так:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    console.log(randomInRange(200_000, 1_000_000) / 1_000_000);
}
```

> ```
> $ node random_in_range.js
> 0.288691
> 0.283178
> 0.422066
> 0.690297
> 0.592872
> 0.575667
> 0.633409
> 0.49091
> 0.637342
> 0.893647
> 0.90158
> 0.992978
> 0.338509
> 0.780983
> 0.954807
> 0.35444
> 0.380894
> 0.722978
> 0.670167
> 0.357568
> ```

Comment: Но ведь вы просто эксплуатируете алгоритм преобразование чисел в строку, используемый `console.log()`. Генерируемые числа содержат больше шести знаков после точки. В этом легко убедиться, если в строку преобразовывать так: `( randomInRange(200_000, 1_000_000) / 1_000_000 ).toFixed(17)`.

Comment: @wlolo, генерируется с равной вероятностью нужное количество точек. И каждая из этих точек настолько близка к нужному результату насколько это позволяет способ хранения чисел. Если этого недостаточно, не делите на миллион, используйте целые случайные числа. А в условиях задачи (выдать вещественные числа) это лучший возможный результат.

Comment: @wlolo, два других ответа выдают строки, не числа, выглядящие как то что нужно. Но если вы переведёте эти строки в вещественные числа, вы получите числа из моего ответа.

Comment: Ну так, судя по ответу ТС, способ хранения чисел — это строки. Хотите сказать, что закодировать вещественное число `2 / 10` с помощью строки `"0.20000000000000001"` — это лучший возможный результат?

Comment: @wlolo, хранить строки вместо чисел немного неправильно, как мне кажется. Случайные числа потому так зовутся что они числа. :)

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту задачу такой вот простой функцией:

```
function rand6(a, b) {
    let randombek = Math.random() * ((b * 1000000) - (a * 1000000) + 1) + (a * 1000000);
    let randombekFix = randombek.toFixed();
    let returnbek = (randombekFix / 1000000).toFixed(6);
    return returnbek;
}
rand6(0.20, 0.80);
```

Answer (score 0):

раз пошла такая пьянка, вот вариант с использованием стандартных linux утилит:

```
printf "0.%06d\n" `shuf -i 200000-999999 -n 1`
```